# Angular Universal 17 - Alternatives to deployurl

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-cli, angular-universal

In Angular 17 the deployUrl was removed with use with Universal and SSR.  The variable allowed you to serve css, js, and the assets folder under a non-root uri.  For example `/my/super/awesome/app`.  In going through the Angular Universal 17 docs there is not a way to serve css, js, and assets from any other route than `/`.

Has anyone else run into this, are you just using Nginx to do rewrites to get around this?

Comment: Did you already check this thread on github ? long story short, deployUrl is gone and not replaced. You are supposed to base everything on --base-href=[full_url]. => https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22485

Comment: There is a start of a discussion about this issue on Github. Hopefully Angular can address the gaps they left by deprecating deployUrl as they promised.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26411

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your path ends with / like --base-href /my/super/awesome/app/ otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This feature returned in version 17.3.0.
Upgrade:

```
ng update @angular/cli
ng update @angular/core
```

Edit angular.json

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "options": {
      "deployUrl": "/my/super/awesome/app/"
```

Or just:

```
ng build --deploy-url=/my/super/awesome/app/
```

See: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases